# Why i can get the substring from this string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, indexof

I'm trying to get the last name "yessine" from a string that i got it by

```
page.findElement(By.xpath("xxx")) .getAttribute("innerText");
```

the String is KCHAOU YESSINE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxYmx.png)

so i want to get yessine only but the `.indexOf("&nbsp;");` is -1 also the `.indexOf(" ");` is also -1, i tried many things, always the position of the " " or the `&nbsp;` is -1 i tried to save the string in .txt file and read from it, didn't worked, always getting -1 and the full name

some tries

```
if (iend < 0) {
            String decodedXML= StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(nomPos);
            System.out.println(decodedXML);
            System.out.println(iend);  //<- -1
            String pre=decodedXML.trim();
            String[] text_arr = pre.split(" ", 2); 
            String A = text_arr[1].toLowerCase();
            String ACaps = A.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + A.substring(1, A.length());
            return ACaps;
```

also

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("temp\\nom.txt");
            try {
                Files.write(path1, Arrays.asList(text_arr));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             String nom = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("temp\\nom.txt")));
                String[] text = nom.split(" ", 2); // this will give abc
                System.out.println(nom.substring(nom.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));

            String A = text[1].toLowerCase();
            String ACaps = A.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + A.substring(1, A.length());
            return ACaps;
```

always same results,

other names that doesn't have &nbps; work fine

how i can do that ?

Comment: You probably need to use the actual character for non breaking space (\u00a0). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: @RogerLindsjö  `int iend = nomPos.indexOf("u00a0");
    System.out.println(iend);`
still getting -1

Comment: @RogerLindsjö `"\u00A0"` work like a charm, thanks